# how to make search query results show up as links to their pages

Tags: search, hyperlink

I am new to php as you can see :)

how can i make the search query results show up as links to their pages. do i need to add to my database a 'links' column in my pages table? Then search_output them out?

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$search_output = "";
if(isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != ""){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    {
        $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE MATCH (page_title,page_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery'))";

    }
    include_once("db_connects.php");
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($count > 1){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

            $id = $row["id"];
            $title = $row["title"];


            $search_output .= "";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />$sqlCommand";
    }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
Search For: 
  <input name="searchquery" type="text" size="44" maxlength="88"> 


</select>
<input name="myBtn" type="submit">
<br />
</form>
<div>
<?php echo $search_output; ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to append all the output from the query fetch, to your $search_output string.

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $id = $row["id"];
        $title = $row["title"];
        $search_output .= "<a href='".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/".$title."'>".$title."</a><br>";
        }
```

But it also depends on how your links look as well, they might not be as simple as above, or might link externally.  Then in that case, yes an extra field where you hardinput the link might be useful.

**NEW EDIT TO ANSWER NEXT QUESTION...**

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $id = $row["id"];
        $title = $row["title"];
        $link = $row["links"];
        $search_output .= "<a href='".$link."'>".$title."</a><br>";
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I think a hardinput into a link field is necessary. how would i do that?

Comment: Well you would go to your pages table, and add a field named 'links', then just add $link = $row['links'], to that mysql_fetch_array.  Then replace the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] stuff with $link.  That is....if you put the whole address with the http:// into that column, then just put $link between the quotes of <a href=''>.

Comment: yes that is waht i did but Notice: Undefined index: links blahblahblah at line 22 is showing up. i think the id and title where defined in the sqlCommand? because the field name for title is actually page_title

Comment: did you remember to add links into that sqlCommand?   $sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, **links**, page_title AS title FROM pages WHERE MATCH (page_title,page_body) AGAINST ('$searchquery'))";

Comment: silly me.. thank you Kyle!! you have been most helpful.. just wanna say none of the links would work but when i added http:// in front of the links they worked. not sure why this is..

Comment: You're welcome :)  And to answer the http:// thing....Basically, any text in the <a href> tag without a protocol is assumed to be a relative path from your site, if there is no / or protocol.  Meaning if your page is www.mypage.com and you link <a href="www.newsite.com">  it wont go to www.newsite.com  It will go to www.mypage.com/www.newsite.com, the http:// lets it now its not a 'relative' path