# How to make a link from a database result appear as hyperlink?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a database, which when queried, can return results that sometimes contain a web address. If there is an address in the results, it will always be located in the "Location" field of the database.

Currently, when the results return, it returns as a line of text (which the user would have to copy/paste into a browser window).

How do I make it return a hyperlink, instead of just a line of text?

**Here's my PHP...**

```
if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop

                echo "<p><strong><u><h2>".$results['SchoolName']."</h2></u></strong>".$results['text']."</p>";
                echo "<p><strong>Location:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['SchoolLocation']."".$results['text']."</p><br />";
                echo "<p><strong>Notes:</strong>&nbsp;".$results['SchoolNotes']."".$results['text']."</p><br /><br /><br />";
                // posts results gotten from database(title and text) you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following

            echo "<br /><br /><br /><strong><h2>"."This is great news! The school you searched for is NOT on our Illegitimate High School List..."."</h2></strong>";
        }

    }
    else{ // if query length is less than minimum
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

I did some research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801173/how-to-make-search-query-results-show-up-as-links-to-their-pages), but I don't see how to apply it to my situation.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Where are you trying to output a link?

Comment: I appreciate that. However, in my current situation, I'd like to improve the way the results are returned. I have your site up and I will begin the conversion over to MySQLi (looks like it'll work better for me). Can you help with my current predicament?

Comment: @brbcoding -I am trying to output a link where you see the "SchoolLocation" field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your field name from DB is Location:

```
echo "<p><strong>Location:</strong>&nbsp;<a href='".$results['Location']."' target='_blank'>".$results['SchoolLocation']."</a>".$results['text']."</p><br />";
```

Comment: Appending the above comment... It worked, but it returns all results located in that field as a hyperlink. How would I adjust this so that "if" the results contain a link, then it will be hyperlinked?  Additionally, when I click a link in the results, it just opens a blank webpage, but that's it. Can you help?

Comment: you can add regular expression in conditional, for example:
if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/',$results['Location'],$output)){
echo "<p><strong>Location:</strong>&nbsp;<a href='".$output."' target='_blank'>".$results['SchoolLocation']."</a>".$results['text']."</p><br />";
}else{
//output without anchor tag
}

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. It actually didn't display any results. I'll keep researching.